# Export selenium / junit test base using maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I am working on a Selenium test base that will eventually be exported, and run on a specific machine.

The target machine has only a JRE, and no JDK.

How can I export my test base to be able to run the JUnit test classes on this target machine, without having a JDK available?

If I try running, from my local machine,

```
mvn package
```

All the selenium tests are executed locally, and the package jar only contains `src` files, nothing from `test`.

Is it possible to package the existing maven project as a runnable jar while keeping the Test classes intact?

Answer (score 0):

To compile your application's test code use `compiler:testCompile` as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html)